# Combine two polygons in the same layer

Tags: qgis, layers, editing

I have a map to make and I accidentally right clicked midway through an outline. Therefore it made two different polygons in the same layer I believe. I do not know how to combine them. I have tried editing the shape of the polygons but only managed individually yet I somehow made it worse. I don't know my way around this QGIS, it is my first time using this tool.

*[image]*

Comment: When you edit the polygon, the changes are not saved. So if the was looked correct when you started eding, then you introduced the error, simply toggle editing and **don't save** the changes to get back before you started editing. Another option is to use Vertex tool and delete the additional vertices you clicked accidentally. For more help, please describe exactly what you had at the beginning and, step by step, what you did. Also describe what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: thank you. I\ think ill just restart